# Pegar somente o primeiro registro de cada condição

Tags: sql, postgresql, query

Boa tarde!

Tenho a seguinte tabela:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como obter somente o primeiro registro de cada id_uni_sching? Ou seja, preciso obter os id_sching 534.382 e 524.075 (Primeiro horário de cada id_uni_sching) ?

Obs: Estou usando Postgres

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vc pode agregar usando a funcao array_agg e acessar o index do item que quer, se ordenar por alguma coluna com timestamp fica perfeito.

```
select id_uni_sching,
      (array_agg(id_sching order by sta_sching))[1] as primeiro_id_sching,
      (array_agg(dta_sching order by sta_sching))[1] as primeiro_dta_sching,
      (array_agg(sta_sching order by sta_sching))[1] as primeiro_sta_sching
from seguinte_tabela
group by id_uni_sching
```

Vc pode fazer o contrario tbm, ordenando por `sta_sching desc`, obs, estou assumindo que sta_sching eh uma coluna de tempo, se nao vc tera q ir um pouquinho mais a fundo criando uma subquery pra row_number(). Nesse caso vc podera atribuir um numero pra cada row, e ordenar por esse numero.

Comment: Não conhecia a função array_agg, bem interessante e funcionou perfeitamente! Obrigado Marcos, abraços.

Comment: Obtenho resultados errados, dados - `('23ef', 534.383, '12-02-2021', '09:00'), ('23ef', 534.382, '12-03-2021', '11:30'), ('23ef', 534.389, '12-02-2021', '08:30'), ('c557', 524.075, '12-02-2021', '08:00'), ('c557', 524.085, '12-02-2021', '07:00'), ('c557', 524.090, '12-02-2020', '19:00'), ('c557', 524.076, '12-02-2021', '08:30')`

Comment: dado q estou vendo 2ef repetindo como id_uni, acredito q vc nao tenha agrupado por id_uni..
Sempre q vc agrega uma coluna, vc tem q agrupar as restantes q irao se repetir.. assim qualquer valor repetido eh condensado em uma unica row junto com os valores agregados.

Comment: Por que obtemos resultados diferentes? [Tentar](https://rextester.com/GJILLU30109)

Answer (score 1):

Uma solução utilizando `DISTINCT ON`:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ON (id_uni_sching) id_uni_sching, id_sching, dta_sching, sta_sching
FROM tabela1
ORDER BY id_uni_sching, dta_sching, sta_sching;
```

Comment: hmm.. nao sei se soluciona, mas eh novo pra mim esse distinct on(), so conhecia distinct sobre todas as colunas haha.. vlws por compartilhar aew